# Data Sync from PostgreSQL to Google BigQuery to 3rd party tool in real time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Want to replicate the data of PostgreSQL DB to google Big query and whenever there is any insertion/deletion/updation in any table in Big query dataset, want to create a trigger on that and fetch that particular data and send it to 3rd party tool via API request.

For replicating the data from PostgreSQL to Big Query, we are using google data stream. For fetching the changes in google Big Query, we tried using Cloud Function and in that used Eventarc trigger of google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob. But however while using this and querying the big query(the query contains Joins) with where clause on datastream_metadata.source_timestamp, its going into infinite loop and keeps on executing the cloud function again and again. So is there any alternate way to get the data from Big query synced up with 3rd party tool in real time?

Comment: Will the data updated in BigQuery independently of the Postgres source? If no, you can reuse the datastream flow from Postgres to send these changes to 3rd party application. If yes, you need to wait. Something is cooking on BigQuery side, more in Q1 or Q2 next year

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, the data updated in BigQuery is independent of the Postgres source. As of now, is there any alternative way for the same?

Comment: Not really, and absolutely not reliable and easy. Today, you can have the data appended to the table, but not the updated and the deleted ones (not in real time, but with a simple query)